# How does LiveData know when data is changed in Room Database?

Tags: android, mvvm

I am learning Mvvm pattern in android, and I don't understand one thing. How Live Data knows when data has changed in Room Database? I have this code:

Fragment:

```
 newUserViewModel.getListItemById(itemId).observe(this, new Observer<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable User user) {
            tv.setText(user.getName());
        }
    });
```

View model:

```
 public LiveData<User> getListItemById(String itemId){       
    return repository.getListItem(itemId);
}
```

Repository:

```
 public LiveData<User> getListItem(String itemId){
    return userDao.getUSerByID(itemId);
}
```

DAO:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE itemId = :itemId")
LiveData<User> getUSerByID(String itemId);// When this query gets executed and how live Data knows that our Table is changed?
```

let's say we inserted new User in Database. When is `@Query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE itemId = :itemId")` gets executed  when there is new data in our database?) and How LiveData knows that we have new User in table and callback Observer owner that data has changed?

Comment: Because, internally, Room stores the observers and notifies them through LiveData after the INSERT statement

Comment: Ok,  that make sense now, thanks a lot for help. You can make this comment as answer so i can check.

Comment: Can you just please clarify workflow of  "notifies them through LiveData"? So INSERT is done how LiveData in this case notifies Observer? With some callback method? And after notification observer call : newUserViewModel.getListItemById(itemId)

Comment: By the way, according to documentation, you shouldn't call repository.getListItem from your view model. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After diving in the [Android Room code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:room/), I found out some things:

1. Room annotation processor generates code from Room annotations (`@Query`, `@Insert`...) using [javapoet](https://github.com/square/javapoet) library
2. Depending on the result type of the query ([QueryMethodProcessor](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:room/room-compiler/src/main/kotlin/androidx/room/processor/QueryMethodProcessor.kt;l=42)), it uses a "binder" or another one. In the case of `LiveData`, it uses [LiveDataQueryResultBinder](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:room/room-compiler/src/main/kotlin/androidx/room/solver/query/result/LiveDataQueryResultBinder.kt;l=31).
3. `LiveDataQueryResultBinder` generates a `LiveData` class that contains a field `_observer` of type [InvalidationTracker.Observer](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:room/room-runtime/src/main/java/androidx/room/InvalidationTracker.kt;l=666), responsible of listen to database changes.

Then, basically, when there is any change in the database, `LiveData` is invalidated and client (your repository) is notified.

Comment: is it not very efficient for some conditional query? for example, I just pull a subset to fill my ListView, but whenever any unrelated data inserted, my observing LiveData is invalidated then the ListView will be refilled.

Comment: But how does it knows there's an update? Does it use polling?

Answer (score -3):

Add to your Dao a query to be used just for notifications, something like:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM my_table")
public LiveData<List<MyItem>> changeNotif();
```

and then in your activity listen to changes like this:

```
LiveData<List<MyItem>> items = AppDatabase.getAppDatabase().itemDao().changeNotif();
items.observe(this, new Observer<List<MyItem>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(List<MyItem> myItems) {
    }
});
```

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. The question is not asking about the usage of the API rather how it works internally